# Is there any compare data between intel IPL function and ImageMagicK function?

Tags: c++, image-processing, imagemagick, intel-ipp

Now I am using ImageMagick Library for solving image processing problems.
But I found a IPP Library of the Intel.

So I want to know Is there any compare data between intel IPL function and ImageMagicK function?

especially, I want to know between speed of processing. and performances.

When I using gaussian blur of the ImageMagicK it is need to be a lot of time to processing.
1024x768 image and I use gaussian blur sigma 0~20 and radian 0~255.

But it is a quit a bit need to time for processing.

So I hope IPP will more faster than ImageMagicK processing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What stops you to measure? Of course, you need to know what task/code should be measured. The library itself, without any using code, has no speed.

Comment: @deviantfan yep I have update.